# Missing ListView Control in RIDER

Tags: c#, winforms, rider

I am fairly new to C# and Rider. I was creating a Windows Forms Application in .NET Framework 4.8.

I checked the Designer Toolbox and saw that ListView is not available as one of the options.

Any solution for this or would I have to be forced to move to Visual Studio? (I came from IntelliJ so Rider was more familiar for me)

Comment: Are you checking "All components" or "Common components"? You should type in the search box to confirm where ListView is.

Comment: I can only see "Common Components". I don't have any other tabs. Tried searching aswell, comes up empty

Comment: See if others reported such bugs, or report yours when there is none, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER

Answer (score -1):

This is a known issue and is in progress. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-30456/.
So far, you can add required assembly through "Toolbox manager"